# Bringing image in front of SVG fill

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG element,  `dining-table`. I would like to display the image in front of the the `dining-table`.

- I need to leave the image element in the `dining-table` element because the `dining-table` elements are wrapped in a for loop.
- `z-index` does not work with SVG elements, as far as I know.
- Adding opacity to the fill color is not what I want to do.

```css
.dining-table rect {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  fill: white;
  stroke: #0A7A74;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500px" height="500px">
  <g class="dining-table">
    <image xlink:href="http://kommis.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/410147-200.png" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="50px"/>
      <rect>
      </rect> 
   </g>
</svg>
```

Here is the JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ye0atc3p/7/

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ye0atc3p/10/ ?

Comment: Yes like this. Thanks for your answer. I did not realize that you simply need to put the `image` element after the `dining-table` element.